# Insert current row number into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-function

I have the following table in `SQL Server`:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTempPo](
    [TempPoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [guid]  AS ([dbo].[GetIdentity]()),
    [Qty] [int] NULL,
    [MobileBrandID] [int] NULL,
    [MobileID] [int] NULL
)
```

I need to `insert` the current `row number` to the `guid` column every time a new row is added. I tried to use the following `function` but it's not working as expected:

```
ALTER FUNCTION GetIdentity() 
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
   RETURN (SELECT top 1 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TempPoID asc)FROM tblTempPo)
END
```

Comment: The column is called `guid` but it stores an `int` ?!?!? That'll be a maintenance nightmare down the line!! You should always adhere to the **Principle of Least Surprise** - if something is **called** `guid` - everyone would expect it to be of type `Guid`, too .....

Comment: Also: doing this every time a row is added will be a HUGE performance bottleneck! **WHY** do you need to **store** this?? Why can't you just compute it (in your query) when needed, on the fly, and be up to date all the time??

Comment: If you want to have UniqueId for `Guid` column you can set the default value as `NEWID()`.

Comment: I tend to agree with marc_s, but if you REALLY wanna do this, consider two things: store the row number on an int column, not called "Guid" and NOT being a primary key (as he said); and also consider doing it on a post-adding trigger, so the DB does it for you automagically.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `GetIdentity()` will probably always return 1 but it is not a sure thing because you are using `select top 1...` without an `order by` clause.
If you want the highest value returned by `row_number()` you need to add `order by 1 desc` which would be the same as doing `SELECT count(*) from tblTempPo`.

Fixing `GetIdentity()` like that will not help much in your situation because `[guid]  AS ([dbo].[GetIdentity]())` will give you a computed column that is evaluated every time you **query** the table and not when you **insert** a new row. You will always have the same value for all rows.

You could use a function that takes the `TempPoID` as a parameter as a **computed column**.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetIdentity(@P int) 
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
   RETURN (SELECT rn
           FROM (SELECT TempPoID,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TempPoID ASC) AS rn
                 FROM tblTempPo) AS T
           WHERE TempPoID = @P)
END
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTempPo](
    [TempPoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
    [guid] as dbo.GetIdentity(TempPoID),
    [Qty] [int] NULL,
    [MobileBrandID] [int] NULL,
    [MobileID] [int] NULL
```

I have never used this so I can't tell you if it is a good thing to do or not. It might be devastating for your query performance, I just don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with comments and you should change the GUID column name. If you really have to store the `TempPoID` column twice use computed column. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblTempPo (
    [TempPoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [second_id] AS TempPoID,
    [Qty] [int] NULL,
    [MobileBrandID] [int] NULL,
    [MobileID] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO #tblTempPo (Qty, MobileBrandID, MobileID) VALUES 
(10, 10, 15), (20, 23, 45), (55, 23, 12), (10, 1, 1)

SELECT * FROM #tblTempPo

DROP TABLE #tblTempPo
```

If you need more complicated approach - use trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It's all no good idea, but if you REALLY need it, try trigger:

```
create table [dbo].[tblTempPo](
[TempPoID] [int] identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
[guid]  int,
[Qty] [int] NULL,
[MobileBrandID] [int] NULL,
[MobileID] [int] NULL
)
go

create trigger [dbo].[tblTempPo_Trig] on [dbo].[tblTempPo] instead of insert as
declare @cnt int
select @cnt = count(*)
from [dbo].[tblTempPo] with(nolock)
insert into [dbo].[tblTempPo]([guid], [Qty], [MobileBrandID], [MobileID])
select @cnt+row_number() over (order by [TempPoID]), [Qty], [MobileBrandID], [MobileID] from inserted
go

insert into [dbo].[tblTempPo]([Qty], [MobileBrandID], [MobileID]) values (0, 0,0), (0, 0,0), (0, 0,0), (0, 0,0)
insert into [dbo].[tblTempPo]([Qty], [MobileBrandID], [MobileID]) values (0, 0,0), (0, 0,0), (0, 0,0), (0, 0,0)

select * from [dbo].[tblTempPo]

go
drop table [dbo].[tblTempPo]
go
```